# ui5 init for new project fails

Tags: ui5-tooling

```
ui5 init --verbose
verb cli:middlewares:base using @ui5/cli version 2.6.4 (from /X/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ui5/cli/bin/ui5.js)
verb cli:middlewares:base using node version v14.15.1

⚠️  Process Failed With Error

Error Message:
Could not detect project type: Could not find 'webapp' or 'src' / 'test' folders.
Applications should only have a 'webapp' folder.
Libraries should only have a 'src' and (optional) 'test' folder.

Stack Trace:
Error: Could not detect project type: Could not find 'webapp' or 'src' / 'test' folders.
Applications should only have a 'webapp' folder.
Libraries should only have a 'src' and (optional) 'test' folder.
    at getProjectType (/X/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ui5/cli/lib/init/init.js:54:9)
    at Object.init (/X/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ui5/cli/lib/init/init.js:92:23)
    at async Object.initCommand.handler (/X/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ui5/cli/lib/cli/commands/init.js:22:24)
```

All I had to do is to first `mkdir webapp` and proceeding further succeeds. Am I doing something wrong or is the documentation/tool incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a misunderstanding.

`ui5 init` from the tooling will only create the `ui5.yaml` required to use `ui5 serve` later to preview your (existing) app, it will **not** generate an app.

It would be good if you begin your UI5 app with one of the [UI5 Templates](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/30/ui5ers-buzz-35-ui5-templates-your-easy-start-into-ui5-development/) and
adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[Check these two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su7av.png)

### project folder ->open cmd

1. mkdir webapp
2. npm init --yes
3. ui5 init

Comment: Your answer format is not fit for Stackoverflow Answer Guide. Please edit it. For instance, don't use annoying bold, high punto representation and give in a code block any console input.